# Upgrade from velocity 1.4 to recent - What to expect?

Tags: upgrade, velocity, legacy-code

I have to maintain an old legacy codebase that uses velocity 1.4 for several things.
The customer is pretty conservative when it comes to updates, so we have to cope with
this ancient dependencies.
I'd like to solve a problem with recursive macros, which is not possible in this version.

So I thought that an update may be the solution.

Has anyone an idea what incompatibilities have been introduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading from 1.4 to 1.7 (which allows for recursive macros) requires no code and template changes in my experience. The only thing you may get are deprecation warnings (e.g. 'XMLToolboxManager has been deprecated.', 1.7 deprecates even more, so you may just want to upgrade to 1.6 if you just need macro recursion), but everything should still work as before.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my developer machine and have noticed no (new) bugs yet. But the software is pretty big, so my click-through testing coverage is far from complete... ;-) But thanks for the information!

Comment: But whatever you do, don't use 1.5.  It is an abomination performance-wise. :)

Comment: I upgraded to 1.7 it went super smooth and now I have recursive macros with macro variable scope :-)